# I am trying to convert an video mp4 file to Audio mp3 format by using MoviePy module but it is showing me Nonetype error

Tags: python, moviepy, pytube

```
def download_audio():
#try:
    b2.config(text="Please wait...")
    b2.config(state=DISABLED)
    stream = yt.streams.filter(res="480p")
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if path == None:
        return
    stream[0].download(path)
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,i),os.path.join(path,i.replace(' ','_')))
    title = yt.title.replace(' ','_')
    print(title)
    print(path)
    video = VideoFileClip(os.path.join(path+"//"+title+".mp4"))
    print(video)
    video.audio.write_audiofile(os.path.join(path+"//"+title+".mp3"))
```

[This is the Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMzWM.png)
Attribute Error : NoneType object has no attribute write_audiofile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
Actually streams.filter("480p") was giving me a video only stream with no audio that's why the nonetype error because it had no audio object.
solved it by doing streams.filter(progressive=True).

```
def download_audio():
#try:
b2.config(text="Please wait...")
b2.config(state=DISABLED)
stream = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True)
path = filedialog.askdirectory()
if path == None:
    return
stream[0].download(path)
for i in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path,i),os.path.join(path,i.replace(' ','_')))
title = yt.title.replace(' ','_')
print(title)
print(path)
video = VideoFileClip(os.path.join(path+"//"+title+".mp4"))
print(video)
video.audio.write_audiofile(os.path.join(path+"//"+title+".mp3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def download_audio():
#try:
    b2.config(text="Please wait...")
    b2.config(state=DISABLED)
    stream = yt.streams.filter(res="480p")
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if path == None:
        return
    stream[0].download(path)
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,i),os.path.join(path,i.replace(' ','_')))
    title = yt.title.replace(' ','_')
    print(title)
    print(path)
    video = VideoFileClip(os.path.join(path,title+".mp4"))
    print(video)
    video.audio.write_audiofile(os.path.join(path,title+".mp3"))
```

The path needs to be built up in os.path by using comma not by "//".

Comment: well, comma is of no use here actually I needed only one slash "/" figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try `video.write_audiofile(os.path.join(path+"//"+title+".mp3"))`

You might be better off using ffmpeg for converting videos or opencv for all video management.

Comment: The point of using `os.path.join` is to pass each part of the path in as a separate argument, not to connect them all with `+` beforehand.

Comment: That's right of course, I copy pasted original line only removed the `.audio` part,